# Accessing Apple Magic Trackpad input data in a C++ program

Tags: c++, macos, trackpad

I'd like to read trackpad multitouch gesture and coordinate data into my C++ program. Where can I find some introductory tutorials on doing this?

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669909/extending-functionality-of-magic-mouse-do-i-need-a-kext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is indeed objective-c++, which is just a mix of c++ and objective-c. It's very powerful because you can start using all the Apple frameworks in your C++ projects.

You should learn a bit of objective-c, rename some .m files to .mm (or .cpp files to .mm) and read through the apple documentation on touch events. ( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/touchesBeganWithEvent: )

Or if objective-c scares you, check out this multitouch trackpad addon for OpenFrameworks https://github.com/jens-a-e/ofxMultiTouchPad

Comment: don't like the idea of picking up another language just to do this, but I guess it's it's the canonical approach...

Comment: I know how you feel, I also came from c++. But learning obj-c is easy, interesting and so useful. Just think about all the Apple APIs you'll be able to use!

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html).
To use Cocoa frameworks in your C++ program use [Objective-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c-and-can-i-use-this-language-in-xcode).